# Google Play revenue sharing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

recently I have finished my Android game, I've done testing and it seems to be ready to hit the market. It is supposed to be free, with in-app purchases. The problem is that Google Wallet Merchant registration is not supported in my country. I have heard that there are companies that would help me with this, if I give them a percentage of my revenue, and that's fine for me.

Googleing didn't help, so I'm here asking if there's a company that provides this service?(and no, I don't have any relatives or friends that would be willing to do this for me)